# how to dom element select by item number with CSS selector

Tags: css

I want to select the sections according to the item number.
:nth-child and :nth-of-type don't work for me. I can't select sections separately. I want to select section 1 and section 3 in my code below.

```css
section:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<section>section 1</section>
<section>section 2</section>


<div class="container">
  <section>section 3</section>
  <section>section 4</section>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <section>section 5</section>
</div>
```

But this method doesn't work properly.

Note: I want solution without javascript.

Comment: Can you briefly explain your question. So as we can help you out.

Comment: You have section element at various level, which 1st and 3rd element you want to be selected.

Comment: Its working properly. nth-child work with the dom at consecutive and in same hierarchy. there are 3 sets of section. 1st set: section 1 and section 2; 2nd set(container div): section 3 and section 4; and 3rd set (footer): section 5. It is coloring the first child of these three sets.

Comment: For example: i want select only section 1 and set color red. Then select only section 2 and  set color aqua.

Comment: @KajemulHaque I think he wants to use 'nth-of-type' which doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to achieve, but you have divs (container, footer) in the way.

Comment: I think with both ```nth-of-type``` and ```nth-child```, the elements need to be children of the same div

Answer (score -1):

Try using `nth-child(n)` instead.

```
section:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  color: aqua;
}
```

Using `nth-of-type` gets **every other element** while `nth-child` **finds the specific item index**.

Comment: He wants to find the item simply according to item number. "I want to select the sections according to the item number" for which neither nth-child nor nth-of-type is working.